# How to write a function in a Lisp. Compile that Lisp file. and then run that Lisp program

Tags: lisp

Write, compile, and test a funtion in Common Lisp that takes a list and counts the total of positive integers in the List. Must compile then execute .lisp file containing the function. after compilation of that file start to pass it list where after the results for the result to be produced therefore testing the correctness of the function.

I have the function. I can run it rawly by putting if directly into the Lisp command line. Simply put I just need to figure out how to compile the file and then pass it list on the terminal to test it.

(count-if #'(lamda (x) (> x 0))

i need to compile that 
then for example pass it this ex:: ( 1 2 3 4 5)
and the result should be :: 5
this is because their are 5 values that equal more then 0

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please follow the guideline before asking your question on Stack Overflow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write a file:

```
$ echo "(defun test () (print :test))" > test.lisp
```

In the same directory, start you Common Lisp environment (example with CCL), you have a REPL; compile the file:

```
? (compile-file "test.lisp")
#P"/tmp/test.lx64fsl"
NIL
NIL
```

Note that if you try to run the `test` function, there will be an error because it is undefined in your environment.

Load the resulting object file; if you load `"test"`, the object file is used if available; you could have called `load` directly on the ".lisp" file, but then there are no guarantees the file is compiled or interpreted. That's a minor detail here, you probably should not care about compiling or not at this point.

```
? (load "test")
```

Now, `test` is available in your environment, you can call it:

```
? (test)

:TEST ;; what the function printed
:TEST ;; the returned value, automatically printed by the REPL
```

Without restarting the Lisp environment, you can edit the file, and reload it.
This is a minimalistic setup but that should be enough for starting.

Comment: Is there a way to use the `compile` function to compile all functions inside a lisp file, if for any reason there is no access to `compile-file` (for instance for applications delivered by LispWorks)?

Comment: It seems unlikely that `compile` is present while `compile-file` isn't, based on http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/lw71/DV/html/delivery-171.htm, but I don't know; if that's the case, you can `load` the file first, which might call compile itself; if you want to explicitly compile all functions, you need to open the file, `read` all forms in a loop, `eval` them, and when the result is a symbol that is `fbound`, compile it. This is a bit of hack, but it can do the job if needed.

Comment: This is an answer i got from an application maintainer asking why there isn't any `compile-file` available in the app: __LispWorks-delivered applications (like OpenMusic) embed most of the original Lisp environment, except the compile-file function.__

Comment: @Student In that case you have the following options as far as I know: (1) do not compile, just load the file (2) have your own hobbyist edition of Lispwroks (same version), call `compile-file` in it, and load it in OpenMusic; you might have dependency problems; (3) build OpenMusic from source and run things from here, do not deliver the application, or hack the delivery to include `compile-file`; my guess is that there might be limitations with the hobbyist edition of Lispworks, but I don't know. You will certainly have better answers talking to the maintainers directly.

Comment: I don't understand the part (2) of your answer. What should i load in openmusic after calling compile-file from lw?

Comment: @Student If you own the same version of LispWorks as the one used to start OpenMusic, you can start that Lisp environment, which has `compile-file`. The return value is a pathname to the `.fasl` file resulting from compilation. If you succeed in compiling the file, you should be able to `load` the `.fasl` file from the OpenMusic.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206466/discussion-between-student-and-coredump).